# Auto Save-As PNG in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

I usually have to save my photoshop documents as PNG and on Mac you have to manually select "PNG" option from the dropdown manually using the mouse.

I wonder if its possible somehow to create some kind of a shortcut or a script (applescript) that would select 'PNG' by default? That would save me huge amount of time!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop has a feature called [actions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/11.0/WSB2434464-4A8C-410e-9757-A74A065FA9E6.html) that can automate tasks like this. They work like Microsoft Office macros - you record the keystrokes or mouse actions and then Photoshop plays them back.

Comment: But this would save the files always in the same location, wouldn't it? I mean, my experience with macros is that they play back the *same* steps, and recording an action to save in one location wouldn't be of much use...